# Flashsort is a distribution sorting algorithm showing linear computational complexity O(n)

Tags: sorting

According to Wikipedia,

Flashsort is a distribution sorting algorithm showing linear computational complexity O(n) for uniformly distributed data sets and relatively little additional memory requirement. The original work was published in 1998 by Karl-Dietrich Neubert.

Then why we are not using flashsort instead of quicksort ??

Answer (score 0):

Because in most cases your data isnt uniformly distributed.

Comment: can you give me any practical example

Comment: Simply generate the numbers from 1 to 100 and enshure that each number occurs exactly once. Or use a random number generator that produces each number with the same probability.